# Where are good places to find reference?

Tags: infection, surgery, injury

I'm a special effects makeup artist (these are the guys who do the wounds or injuries for the movies).
I need good reference (images or video) of how all kinds of Injuries look like, to make the stuff based in reality and therefore make it look more real.

However, I'm not a doctor or study medicine, so I don't know good books, or where else to look for.

I know this might be opinion based, but I don't want to know the best, I just would like to know some good sources or go to places.

I know, that this is probably no the right question for this "community", but I don't know where else I could ask it. So If you know, please tell me in the comments below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't actually regarding health (which I think you realize).  I would point you to the image section of trauma.org, however.